# Ordinary differential equations of order zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition

Is $x+y+2=0$ a differential equation without derivatives of order $n$, $n>0$? Could it be called a differential equation (for unknown $y(x)$) of order $0$?

If not, can we define differential equations of order zero?

Comment: I suggest that you add the context where this question arose. What is the motivation to define differential equations of order zero?

Comment: please read n>0 instead of n>1

Comment: You can but why would you do that? I suppose you could say that if you differentiate a differential equation of order zero you get a differential equation of order one... but again why?

Answer (score 2):

You *could* call such equations "zero-order differential equations" but since no derivative is actually involved, the name is more misleading than  helpful. I would call it an *algebraic equation* for $y$, to emphasize the difference between it and differential equations. Shorter and less confusing.

But if one generalizes from differential operators (like the $k$th derivative) to [pseudo-differential operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-differential_operators), things get more interesting. There are important pseudo-differential operators of order $0$, such as 
the [Hilbert transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/813605/), and one could consider equations involving them: say, solving
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{u(x)}{x-t}\,dt = f(t)
$$ 
for $u$. The nature of pseudo-differential operators of order $0$ is such that they are usually thought of as (singular) *integral* operators, and so the equations would be usually called *integral equations*. But occasionally one sees "pseudodifferential equations of order $0$", for [example here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01218505):

> In the present paper we prove the stability of a nodal spline collocation method for (locally) strongly elliptic zero order pseudodifferential equations